# Where in insert statement using sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

```
var user = await db.QueryAsync<individual>("insert into usersinfo (Image) values ('" +img+ "') where Id=" +userID);
```

This is the error:

> Additional information: near "where": syntax error

Comment: What are the values of img and userID

Comment: Where is table design? Do userinfo have id field, what type it is? Is it hard to post relevant information?

Comment: Do you want to do an insert or an update? Not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Supports an Update Command, can you use this?

```
UPDATE 
    Table
SET 
    Field = VALUE 
WHERE
    Id = userID
```

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` command in sql does not support the `where` clause, unless used with the `insert into ... select` form.

Your statement seems not to feature the `insert into select` form, so it should be set to:

```
     insert into usersinfo (Image) values ('" +img+ "')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sqllite expert, but in SQL there is `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1
col1,
col2,
col3
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM table1
    WHERE ...;
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)